# MongoDB - limit access to other databases using a connectionString

Tags: mongodb

I want to create multiple databases, say `db_1`, `db_2`, etc. I have a single user called `dashboard`.

Now, I have a dashboard, and I want to limit access to the dbs, i.e. I want to use a connectionString such that the user `dashboard` only has access to `db_1` and another connectionString such that the user `dashboard` only has access to `db_2`.

For example, if I were to use `mongosh "mongodb+srv://dashboard:MY_PASSWORD@IP_ADDRESS/db1?tls=true&authSource=admin&replicaSet=IP_ADDRESS"`, you can the change the database to `db2` if you want to. But I want to prevent that - that connection should only have access to `db1`

This can be accomplished by creating different users with limits on what they read, but I was hoping this could be done via a single user.

Comment: No chance! Create different users and grant roles accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like you are wanting if the user `dashboard` is a user *on each individual database*, and not in the more "global" `admin` database.

The `authSource=admin` in your query string tells MongoDB which database to use to authenticate, and since you are pointing to `admin` it will always use the same user, the one in the `admin` database.

> If two users have the same name but are created in different databases, they are two separate users. If you want to have a single user with permissions on multiple databases, create a single user with a role for each applicable database.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-users/#authentication-database

So you'd need to create a separate `dashboard` user **in each database**.

The docs and steps here maybe helpful:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/create-users/#create-additional-users-for-your-deployment